# Is it dangerous opening port 3000 of the server?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy, pm2

I want to deploy my Angular + NodeJS application. My NodeJS application runs on `http://localhost:3000` on the server. And my Angular application tries to send it's requests to the server with this prefix address: `http://server.ip.address:3000`. I opened the port 3000 of the server with the following commands to help my program works and it works fine by now.

```
irewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

But I am not sure if I did a good job or not?

My Angular app runs on nginx and my NodeJS app runs on PM2. I also tried to setting a reverse proxy as you can see below inside `etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but it didn't work and just opening port 3000 worked for me!

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /demo/stock-front9/dist/strategy;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            #proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            #proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then

            # as directory, then redirect to index(angular) if no file found.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

What is the best way to deploy Angular + NodeJS application and how can I do it?

Comment: change your ajax'y code to not use a port, then locally when developing its going to use 3000 and on production it will use 80 which then nginx passes to 3000, opening it up is not dangerous but its bypassing nginx exposing upstream host and port, ie your have issues if wanting to use cloudflare and/or possible cors

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I think Express server runs `localhost:3000` by default. You mean I can remove port number(3000) from my requests in Angular code?

Comment: nginx will handle the forwarding to 3000 from 80.. yeah change your Angular code so does not include port. ie dont do `url: ':3000/api/endpoint`, just do `url: '/api/endpoint` then if the url is localhost:3000 or example.com it will inherit the domain and port

Comment: also you need to use proxy_pass to forward onto express, not try_files

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I tried what you said but didn't work!

Comment: did you fix the proxy_pass?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Yes I uncommented them and restarted nginx.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: When I activate reverse proxy it shows Express welcome message!

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the app by just assigning port to process.env.PORT, and put the whole angular build in a public/src folder and give the public folder path in node server file.

You can take reference here https://github.com/Ris-gupta/chat-application

Answer (score 0):

There's no best way but there some best practices. Opening port directly on a server is not good solution. I would suggest you to use docker and publish your application inside container with NGINX. Also you can deploy your backend server in same way.